# How to get duration of a condition (in index length) in a pandas column vectorized

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, numpy, indexing

I have a data set with timeseries data. When a condition is met for a parameter I want to measure for how long that was.
I can for loop through all the positions where the condition changes but that seems to be inefficient.

***What is the best way to do this vectorized?***

**Example:**

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

np.random.seed(0)

# generate dataset:
df = pd.DataFrame({'condition': np.random.randint(0, 2, 24)}, 
                  index = pd.date_range(start='2020', freq='M', periods=24))

df
```

[image]

**Goal:**
my goal is to create a column with the duration of sub sequential occurrences of '1' in this example:
[image]

**what I did so far:**

```
# find start and end of condition:
ends = df[df.condition.diff() < 0].index
start = df[df.condition.diff() > 0].index[:ends.size]

# loop through starts and determine length
for s, e in zip(start, ends):
    df.loc[e, 'duration'] = e - s

# move 1 step back so it matches with last value position
df['duration'] = df.duration.shift(-1)
```

in this example this is pretty fast but the loop makes it slow with bigger datasets. What would be the fastest way to do something like this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mark the first `'0'` in a `'0'` group and mark the first `'1'` in a `'1'` group.  Use `.loc` to select only those rows.  Then do a `diff` on those. Use `.loc` to keep only the `diff`s for the first `'0'` rows.  Then assign back to the original dataframe relying on the index to place the durations into the appropriate rows (almost).  Then `shift` into proper place.

```
s0 = df['condition'].diff() < 0
s1 = df['condition'].diff() > 0

dfc = (
    df.assign(duration=df.loc[s0|s1].index.to_series().diff().loc[s0])
        .assign(duration=lambda x: x['duration'].shift(-1))
)
```

**Result (see timings below this result section)**

```
print(dfc)

            condition duration
2020-01-31          0      NaT
2020-02-29          1      NaT
2020-03-31          1  61 days
2020-04-30          0      NaT
2020-05-31          1      NaT
2020-06-30          1      NaT
2020-07-31          1      NaT
2020-08-31          1      NaT
2020-09-30          1      NaT
2020-10-31          1      NaT
2020-11-30          1 214 days
2020-12-31          0      NaT
2021-01-31          0      NaT
2021-02-28          1  31 days
2021-03-31          0      NaT
2021-04-30          0      NaT
2021-05-31          0      NaT
2021-06-30          0      NaT
2021-07-31          0      NaT
2021-08-31          1  30 days
2021-09-30          0      NaT
2021-10-31          1      NaT
2021-11-30          1  61 days
2021-12-31          0      NaT
```

**Timing DataFrame**

19,135 rows with unique index

**Timing - Question - n4321d**

```
%%timeit
ends = df[df.condition.diff() < 0].index
start = df[df.condition.diff() > 0].index[:ends.size]

# loop through starts and determine length
for s, e in zip(start, ends):
    df.loc[e, 'duration'] = e - s

# move 1 step back so it matches with last value position
df['duration'] = df.duration.shift(-1)

500 ms ± 23 ms per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1 loop each)
```

**Timing - Answer - n4321d**

```
%%timeit
ends = df[df.condition.diff() < 0].index
start = df[df.condition.diff() > 0].index[:ends.size]

df.loc[start, 'temp'] = start
df.temp.ffill(inplace=True)
df.loc[ends, 'duration'] = ends - df.loc[ends, 'temp']
df['duration'] = df.duration.shift(-1)

8.78 ms ± 167 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

**Timing - Answer - jch**

```
%%timeit
s0 = df['condition'].diff() < 0
s1 = df['condition'].diff() > 0

dfc = (
    df.assign(duration=df.loc[s0|s1].index.to_series().diff().loc[s0])
        .assign(duration=lambda x: x['duration'].shift(-1))
)

5.96 ms ± 242 µs per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100 loops each)
```

Comment: thank you this is great, and much simpler!

Answer (score 0):

One way I managed to vectorize it is using [.ffill()](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.ffill.html) to creat a temporary column and forward fill the start times in it. Then substract the start times from the end time:

**ffill start times:**

```
df.loc[start, 'temp'] = start
df.temp.ffill(inplace=True)
```

**output:**
[image]

**Subtract start from end:**

```
df.loc[ends, 'duration'] = ends - df.loc[ends, 'temp']
```

**Output:**
[image]

shift 1 step back to end:

```
df['duration'] = df.duration.shift(-1)
```

This ~1000x Faster on a dataframe with 1e5 rows:
[image]

But I still wonder if this could be further improved...